# redux-toolkit как отправить данные через slice в initialstate, если он представляет собой массив объектов

Tags: redux

как отправить данные через slice в initialstate, если он представляет собой массив объектов

slice:

```
export const mainSlice = createSlice({
name: 'car',
initialState,
reducers: {
    addCar: (state, action) => {
        state.id = action.payload.id
        state.car = action.payload.car
        state.carNumber = action.payload.carNumber
        state.driver = action.payload.driver
        state.trailerNumber = action.payload.trailerNumber
```

отправка данных из компоненты

```
const NewUser = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const [carNumberValue, setCarNumberValue] = React.useState('')
const [TrailerValue, setTrailerValue] = React.useState('')
const [carValue, setCarValue] = React.useState('')
const [idValue, setIdValue] = React.useState('')

const addCarSubmiter = () => {
    counter = counter + 1
    let adder = {
        number: counter,
        id: idValue,
        car: carValue,
        carNumber: carNumberValue,
        driver: '',
        trailerNumber: TrailerValue,
    }

    dispatch(addCar(adder))
}
```

если в initialstate оставить просто объект, все будет работать, но я не могу реализовать crud из-за того, что это не массив,или быть может есть какие-то варианты рендера объекта, не заключая его в массив?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать спарсить этот объект в JSON перед отправкой на сервер.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).